# Can we plot only the latest level in pine script?

Tags: pine-script

this code plots the swing high and swing low levels. But this show both the levels (high level and low level). Can we show only the latest level on the chart.?
Example: you got a swing low at 10:15 there will be a line drawn at this low, but once when there is a new swing high, lets say at 12:30, the old level which was drawn at 10:15 should be hidden and only the new level i.e 12:30's swing high level only should be plotted.
Can we do this?
Thanks in advance.

```
//@version=5
indicator('Last Pivot', overlay=true)

left = 50
right = 25
quick_right = 2  // Used to try and detect a more recent significant swing.

pivot_high = ta.pivothigh(high, left, right)
pivot_lows = ta.pivotlow(low, left, right)

quick_pivot_high = ta.pivothigh(high, left, quick_right)
quick_pivot_lows = ta.pivotlow(low, left, quick_right)

lhigh = ta.valuewhen(quick_pivot_high, high[quick_right], 0)
llow = ta.valuewhen(quick_pivot_lows, low[quick_right], 0)




level1_col = close >= lhigh ? color.green : color.red
level2_col = close >= llow ? color.green : color.red

plot(lhigh, style=plot.style_line, color=level1_col, show_last=1, linewidth=3, trackprice=true)
plot(llow, style=plot.style_line, color=level2_col, show_last=1, linewidth=3, trackprice=true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with the `plot()` function. If, however, you use the `line()` function, you can delete the previous one with the `line.delete()` function.

Below [example](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Drawings.html#deleting-drawings) shows how to do that with a `label`.

```
//@version=4
study("Last Bar Close 1", overlay=true)

c = close >= open ? color.lime : color.red
l = label.new(bar_index, na,
  text=tostring(close), color=c,
  style=label.style_label_down, yloc=yloc.abovebar)

label.delete(l[1])
```

[image]

So, you see? It creates a label but deletes the old one so you only have one label.

**Note:** Instead of creating and deleting the objects over and over again, it is recommended to use the [modifying](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Drawings.html#modifying-drawings) functions and just move the line to a new location. This results in better performance.

## Edit:

`line.new()` has the following signature:

> line.new(x1, y1, x2, y2, xloc, extend, color, style, width) → series
> line

You can add whatever value you want to the `y1` or `y2` arguments then it will move the line on the y-axis. If your script's `overlay=true`, it will be drawn on the main chart.

Comment: Got it, Thank you so much!! And other question i have, I want to add 100 to the swing low and subtract 100 to the Swing high. I know how to do it with the plot() function. But hoe can i do it with the line() function? And also will that be possible to draw the added lines on chart?

Comment: Please see my edit.